# Return API request with node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to make an API call with this function:

```
app.get("/xvma", function(req, res) {
    res.send(fetchSummonerByName("xvma"))
})
```

```
async function fetchSummonerByName(name) {
    // turns name into link format
    while (name.includes(" ")) {
        let spaceSpot = name.indexOf(" ");
        name = name.substring(0, spaceSpot) + space + name.substring(spaceSpot + 1);
    }
    // requests to riot api
    const link = `https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/${name}?${riotKey}`;
    const response = await fetch(link);
    // convert response to json
    let data = await response.json();

    console.log(data); //returns correct value
    return data; //returns '{}'
}
```

The console.log correctly logs out the json object:

```
{
  id: 'S4r9MVi5xp4zrzD-nb8GU_tei_z7S_6zYCp9EAx1vkpYs30',
  accountId: 'BaIczzxrP2sVSR88qjI0vjPxs13o_VczaLELYLM3eX99ew',
  puuid: 'Mdbo0Jm0j0b362vC7_hZbZAtwa4hP5xtFJidUx_lo6UHJ6NYCgnvuSxZAD1a5ueG06n88r5bq4OGwg',
  name: 'xvma',
  profileIconId: 4882,
  revisionDate: 1634684472270,
  summonerLevel: 163
}
```

but on localhost:5000/xvma the only thing that is displayed are curly braces with no value inside of it ('{}').

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetchSummonerByName` is an asynchronous function which returns a promise.
With `res.send(fetchSummonerByName("xvma"))` you are sending that promise as response immediately, but you want to send the result of that resolved promise.

Try something like that:

```js
app.get("/xvma", async function(req, res) {
    res.send(await fetchSummonerByName("xvma"))
})
```

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thanks, that fixed it